# Corollary of Lebesgue decomposition theorem and counter-example

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, geometric-measure-theory

Refferring to the Lebesgue decomposition theorem in [Lebesgue decomposition theorem and fundamental theorem of calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134340/lebesgue-decomposition-theorem-and-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus) there is a corollary when the measure is the Lebesgue measure that states: if $f\in L^p_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $$\lim \frac{1}{|B|}\int_{B}|f-f(x)|^p=0$$ for a.e. $x$, where the limit is taken on balls B each containing $x$ with diameter tending to zero (x is not necessarily the center of the balls). Is there a counter-example of this fact if we choose a general Radon measure (I know taking the limit on balls centered in x holds the same result, but could this not happen if the balls are not centered in $x$?)

Comment: Looking at the proof I guess maybe is the measure is not doubling this couldn't work, but I don't even know real examples od non-doubling measures..

Answer (score 0):

Your conjecture is right. The point is that the balls need not be centered at x.
This theorem and its proof can be found in ***Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions (Revised Edition)*** by Lawrence C. Evans and Ronald F. Gariepy. I have posted the theorem and its proof below.

[Theorem 1.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bywvZ.png)

[Proof of Theorem 1.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMqAX.png)